# sed: How to match these 4 consecutive lines with RegEx for deleting?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a file containing these lines and cuz of the chance of the file getting reset by updates (not in my control), I need to use `sed` or similar method to match those and delete them in the end of a Bash script that executes the update process. Doesn't necessarily have to be RegEx as long as it works, but RegEx is the only way I know and I might never learn the new syntax of alternative method:

```
   if cvars.Number("sv_alltalk", 0) > 0 then
      ErrorNoHalt("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled. Dead players will be able to talk to living players. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0.\n")
      RunConsoleCommand("sv_alltalk", "0")
   end
```

I figured it's better to match whatever is in the beginning and the end of those lines in case the devs screw it up, including changes in indentation. Those lines never repeat, so it'll be safe to match-to-delete the 1st occurence.

My RegEx attempts which don't work, no matches:

**1: {**

```
'^(\t| )+if cvars\.Number\("sv_alltalk", 0\) > 0 then\r\n(\t| )+ErrorNoHalt\("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled\. Dead players will be able to talk to living players\. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0\.\\n"\)\r\n(\t| )+RunConsoleCommand\("sv_alltalk", "0"\)\r\n(\t| )+end.+$'
```

**} 2: {**

```
'(\t| )+if cvars\.Number\("sv_alltalk", 0\) > 0 then\r\n(\t| )+ErrorNoHalt\("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled\. Dead players will be able to talk to living players\. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0\.\\n"\)\r\n(\t| )+RunConsoleCommand\("sv_alltalk", "0"\)\r\n(\t| )+end.+'
```

**} 3: {**

```
'(\t| )+if cvars\.Number\("sv_alltalk", 0\) > 0 then\r(\t| )+ErrorNoHalt\("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled\. Dead players will be able to talk to living players\. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0\.\\n"\)\r(\t| )+RunConsoleCommand\("sv_alltalk", "0"\)\r(\t| )+end.+'
```

**} 4: {**

```
'(\t| )+if cvars\.Number\("sv_alltalk", 0\) > 0 then\n(\t| )+ErrorNoHalt\("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled\. Dead players will be able to talk to living players\. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0\.\\n"\)\n(\t| )+RunConsoleCommand\("sv_alltalk", "0"\)\n(\t| )+end.+'
```

**}**

Answer (score 2):

One (fairly) simple way to do multiline matches in sed, as long as the file fits into memory in one piece, is this:

```
sed -n '1h; 1!H; $ { x; s/pattern/replacement/; p }' filename
```

This reads the whole file into the hold buffer, swaps it back to pattern space when it has everything, substitutes and then prints. So you could do this:

```
sed -n '1h; 1!H; $ { x; s/[\t ]*if cvars\.Number("sv_alltalk", 0) > 0 then\s*\n\s*ErrorNoHalt("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled. Dead players will be able to talk to living players. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0.\\n")\s*\n\s*RunConsoleCommand("sv_alltalk", "0")\s*\n\s*end//; p }' filename
```

Of course, this is exceedingly long and ugly. Depending on how much of the pattern is needed to uniquely identify the match, other ways could (but don't have to be) be more appropriate. For example, if the first and last lines are enough to find the match without false positives, you could use a pattern range to define the section and then exclude it, following the basic form

```
sed -n '/begin-pattern/,/end-pattern/ ! p'
```

`/begin-pattern/,/end-pattern/` selects a range, `!` inverts it, and `p` is the print command, i.e., every line that's not in the range is printed. In your case, it could look like this:

```
sed -n '/^\s*if cvars\.Number("sv_alltalk", 0) > 0 then\s*$/,/^\s*end\s*$/ !p' filename
```

Mind that **this does not expect nested `if`s**. In particular, it will break if there's another `end` in the block, so this will only work if the first line of the pattern identifies the match uniquely and the pattern contains the last line only once. The upside compared to the first approach is that this way sed can work on individual lines and doesn't have to fit the whole file into memory. Although I'd be surprised to see a source code file that's large enough to make anyone worry about this particular problem.

Or, if you know that a specific line of numbers has to be removed after a uniquely identifying first line (probably not the best way in this case) and the first is enough to identify the match,

```
sed '/begin-pattern/ { N;N;N;d }' filename
```

(the number of `N`s defines how many lines are discarded) also works. I only mention this because someone could be lured here with a problem like that by the headline. I don't think it would be a sane way to solve your specific problem.

Comment: I finally actually understood the part '`if the first and last lines are enough to find the match without false positives, you could use a pattern range to define the section and then exclude it, following the basic form`' and it does sound like good idea, but whether the devs will create another `if` with same expression is too weak ice to base on, don't you think ?

Answer (score 0):

sed script

```
sed -i.bak '
/^[[:space:]]*if cvars.Number("sv_alltalk", 0) > 0 then *$/,/^[[:space:]]*end *$/{
/^[[:space:]]*end *$/!{H;d}
/^[[:space:]]*end *$/{H;g;s/.*//g;x
/^[[:space:]]*if cvars.Number("sv_alltalk", 0) > 0 then *\n *\ErrorNoHalt("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled. Dead players will be able to talk to living players. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0.\\n") *\n *RunConsoleCommand("sv_alltalk", "0") *\n *end */d}
}' $1
```

where you call the script with your file

the penultimate line is where you put your "if block"

```
/ *if cvars.Number("sv_alltalk", 0) > 0 then *\n *\ErrorNoHalt("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled. Dead players will be able to talk to living players. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0.\\n") *\n *RunConsoleCommand("sv_alltalk", "0") *\n *end */
```

Notes:

1.Each line begins with  with a space and followed `*` and before the newline character at the end of each line of each line. This is to facilitate matching any spaces before and after each line.

2.In your script there is "`\n`". This is a special character so I used `\\n` to escape the backslash character.

**test sample**

```
if cvars.Number("sv_alltalk", 0) > 0 then
      ErrorNoHalt("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled. Dead players will be able to talk to living players. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0.\n")
      RunConsoleCommand("sv_alltalk", "0")
   end

if cvars.Number("sv_alltalk", 0) > 0 then
      Erro7676rNoHalt("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled. Dead players will be able to talk to living players. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0.\n")
      RunConsoleCommand("sv_alltalk", "0")
   end
```

Note: In the second if block there is  `Erro7676rNoHalt` instead of `ErrorNoHalt`, therefore this if block should not be deleted, since we are  **exactly** matching the whole if block.

**output from this sample**

```
if cvars.Number("sv_alltalk", 0) > 0 then
      Erro7676rNoHalt("TTT WARNING: sv_alltalk is enabled. Dead players will be able to talk to living players. TTT will now attempt to set sv_alltalk 0.\n")
      RunConsoleCommand("sv_alltalk", "0")
   end
```

Comment: may i suggest to use `/^[[:space:]]*` instead of `/^ *` for such kind of file, some use tab, other space char.